# Where can AndroidObservable.fromBroadcast be found now?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, rx-java

Before 1.0.0 there was `AndroidObservable` class with `fromBroadcast` method in  [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/) which would be used to subscribe for broadcast in reactive way. It was mentioned in [Grokking RxJava](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/10/08/grokking-rxjava-part-4/):

> I also like `AndroidObservable.fromBroadcast()`, which allows you to create an `Observable` that works like a `BroadcastReceiver`. Here's a way to be notified whenever network connectivity changes:
>
> ```
> IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
> AndroidObservable.fromBroadcast(context, filter)
>                  .subscribe(intent -> handleConnectivityChange(intent));
> ```

After 1.0.0, RxAndroid dropped a lot of functionality and splitted into RxAndroid itself which now has only threading stuff, [RxLifecycle](https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle) and [RxBindings](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding).

None of them seem to contain `AndroidObservable` with `fromBroadcast` or `fromSharedPreferenceChange`.

Is it implemented in some actual and supported library?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This functionality [was removed in 1.0 release](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/issues/259) as part of modularization effort. You can find a replacement in [RxBroadcast](https://github.com/cantrowitz/RxBroadcast). To use it add a dependency to `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.cantrowitz:rxbroadcast:1.0.0'
```

And use it as follows:

```
Observable<Intent> = RxBroadcast.fromBroadcast(context, intentFilter);
```

Comment: where can be found any proper documentation for RxAndroid?

Comment: RxAndroid is right now a tiny library, you can grok it's source code in less than an hour. All other modules like forementioned [RxBroadcast](https://github.com/cantrowitz/RxBroadcast) and [RxLifecycle](https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle) or [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) live inside their own repositories with fairly good Readmes.

Comment: RxBroadcast only has 29 stars, seems not so many people are using it. Should I use it?

Comment: It's a tiny library, the code is in a good shape and seems to be maintained. I'd say yes there's very little to no risk involved with using it.

Answer (score 1):

In short, it has been removed and I don't know of any replacement yet.

You can see [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/releases/tag/v0.24.0) that it was renamed to `AppObservable`, and then [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/wiki#removed) that it has been removed with the 1.0 release where they did quite some cleaning.

There seem to have been some severe issues.

Comment: It is [said](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/releases/tag/v1.0.0) to have been removed for better modularity. And as said in [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34575878/2196460) it is now available in RxBroadcast. Thanks for your effort though.